# Error: failed to load 'sap/ushell/library.js' from resources/sap/ushell/library.js while enabling ui5-tooling

Tags: sapui5, ui5-tooling

I clone the [demo](https://github.com/ArnaudBuchholz/training-ui5con18-opa) project for ui5-tooling and run it successfully.
however if I do a little change to the project, some errors occur.

#### Reproduce

I did a little change to the manifest.json as below:

```
"sap.ui5": { "dependencies": { "libs": { "sap.ui.core": { "lazy": false }, "sap.m": { "lazy": false }, "sap.ui.layout": { "lazy": false }, "sap.ui.unified": { "lazy": false }, "sap.ushell": { "lazy": false } } },
```

add another lib 'sap.ushell'.
then run the opa again with: 'ui5 serve -o'

#### Symptom

The opa cannot run, in the developers tool of chrome, i found the error:
Error: failed to load 'sap/ushell/library.js' from resources/sap/ushell/library.js: 404 - Not Found...

#### Explaination

I did this change because when I trying to enable ui5 tooling to my existing projects, I can not run OPA successfully.
If i mannually add the lib by 'ui5 add ', then more errors occurs, like 'File not found: /resources/sap/ui/core/themes/sap_belize/base.less'

Comment: Let us know if the below answer was helpful or not. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers.

Answer (score 3):

I was facing the same issue here, following the instructions from Boghyon and the last step is to change your data source in the `index.html` file as well since your are using SAPUI5 now instead of OpenUI5 (i.e, use `src="https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js"` in your bootstrap script).

Answer (score 2):

The lib **`sap.ushell`** is available **only in SAPUI5** since it's not open-sourced.

As of UI5 tooling [`specVersion`](https://sap.github.io/ui5-tooling/stable/pages/Configuration/#specification-versions) 2, you can define whether the application project should use `SAPUI5` or `OpenUI5` in the `ui5.yaml` file.

1. Follow the "Getting Started" page https://sap.github.io/ui5-tooling/pages/GettingStarted/ to prepare consuming *UI5 Tooling* in the project.
2. Ensure that SAPUI5 resources are used instead of OpenUI5:

   1. ```bash
      ui5 use sapui5@latest
      ```
   2. In `index.html`: *

      ```html
      <script id="sap-ui-bootstrap"
        src="resources/sap-ui-core.js"
        data-sap-ui-async="true"
        data-sap-ui-...="..."
      ></script>
      ```

      * In case you'd like to bootstrap SAPUI5 via the CDN URL, see:

      - The "Resolution" section at https://stackoverflow.com/a/60377984/5846045
      - SAP Note [2943781: *"Is the usage of SAP's Content Delivery Network for onPremise systems permitted?"*](https://launchpad.support.sap.com/#/notes/2943781)
3. Add `sap.ushell` to the list of libraries.

   ```bash
   ui5 add sap.ushell
   ```

You can doublecheck the used `framework` and the list of added UI5 libraries in `ui5.yaml` located in the project's root directory.